# call a testcase inside a user defined keyword robot framework

Tags: robotframework

Is there any way I can call a robot framework testcase inside a userdefined keyword. Below is the example

```
*** Test Cases ***
TestCase1
    call a testcase Testcase2
*** Keywords ***
call a testcase
    [Arguments] ${testcasename}
    *** Test cases ***
    ${testcasename}
    do something
```

Comment: not possible. But why would you do that?

Comment: @  Laurent Bristiel Here is my requirement                     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076228/robot-framework-running-multiple-testcases-using-csv-and-for-loop

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to call a test case from within a keyword. If you convert the test case to a keyword, you can then call the keyword from another keyword or test case.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with an example how can I achieve it

Comment: @NandeeshBijoor: if you need that level of help, I suggest you first learn how to write keywords. The robot framework user guide is very helpful, as is the official [Quick Start Guide](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/quickstart/quickstart.html)

Comment: @ Bryan Oakley- I understood. Basically having test scenario as testcase and calling actual testcase as keywords. Problem here is with the reporting. If one keyword fails it will mark whole test as failure.

Comment: @ Bryan Oakley My requirement is this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076228/robot-framework-running-multiple-testcases-using-csv-and-for-loop